# PHP Strange Syntax Error Line 1 Setting Up Mailchimp

Tags: php, html, mailchimp

I have html sending a POST request that reaches php code to process the request...I'm getting a strange error saying theres a syntax error on line 1

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/content/31/9275231/html/subscribe.php on line 1

However I don't see any errors on line 1.

Here is the code (I hid my API key info)

```
<?php
function isValidEmail( $email = null )

{
    return preg_match( "/^
    [\d\w\/+!=#|$?%{^&}*`'~-]
    [\d\w\/\.+!=#|$?%{^&}*`'~-]*@
    [A-Z0-9]
    [A-Z0-9.-]{1,61}
    [A-Z0-9]\.
    [A-Z]{2,6}$/ix", $email );
}

/* Check if email has been posted */
if ( !isset($_POST['email']) ) die();

/* Validate email */
if ( isValidEmail($_POST['email']) ) {

require_once('./MCAPI.class.php');  

// **************************************************************** //

    // Enter your API Key from http://admin.mailchimp.com/account/api/
    $api = new MCAPI('apikey');

    // Enter your list's unique id from http://admin.mailchimp.com/lists/
    // (click the "settings", the unique id is at the bottom of the page) 
    $list_id = 'list_unique_id';

// **************************************************************** //

if($api->listSubscribe($list_id, $_POST['email'], '') === true) {
    echo 'successful';
}else{
    echo 'Error: ' . $api->errorMessage;
    }

} 

else {
    echo 'invalid_email';
}
```

One other peculiar thing: I notice that when I open this php code in textmate it looks fine, but when I open it in vim, all the code is displayed in one line with strange '^M' characters where new lines should be...any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you remove the default argument value? the function is supposed to check something anyway, right?

Comment: ^M (ctrl-M) stands for CR (character code 13) but vim is expecting the line ending LF (character code 10)

Comment: Try  `dos2unix`                .

Answer (score 0):

The weird ^M characters are Windows/DOS line endings. Use this to replace them with Unix line endings:

```
:%s/^V^M/\r/g
```

More info here: http://grx.no/kb/2008/11/17/remove-windows-line-endings-in-vim/

Answer (score 0):

Check the options in your text editor to see if you can make newlines as LFs instead of CRs (or both a CR followed by an LF).  What's happening is your newlines are only CRs, whereas the PHP interpreter is looking for LFs for newlines, so it reads your code as one big line.